# Jquery loop and run the (click) functions each X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this (simplified for here) code which change the background position on click,
but i need to put them in a auto loop too

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".sle1").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-908px 0px'});
    });
    $(".sle2").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-681px 0px'});
    });
    $(".sle3").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-454px 0px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

I mean after 5 seconds of page load this first function runs

```
$(".sle1").click(function() {
       $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-908px 0px'});
});
```

then after 5 second the .sle2 and when it reachs the .sle3 (last function) after 5 seconds it should go back and run the first function again (a loop)

i tried putting ", 5000)" after each function but it didn't work

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) to execute a function every 5 seconds.

To cycle through those three functions, you could store all of them in an array and set i every time to the function that should be called next.

```
var i = 0;
var functions = [
    function() {
        // instead of copying that code, you could also do
        // $(".sle1").click() - or you can just use functions[0]
        // as argument when assigning the click listener.
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-908px 0px'});
        i = 1;
    },
    function() {
        // second animation here
        i = 2
    },
    function() {
        // third animation here
        i = 0
    }
];
window.setInterval(function () {
    functions[i]();
}, 5000);
```

[Edit]: no more ring-counter as that wouldn't work with the clicking.
For future reference: If you don't need the clicking to interfere with the automatic switching and want to archive something similar with only automatic cycling, get rid of th `i=` statements in the functions and instead insert `i++; i%= functions.length` after `functions[i]();`.

Comment: thanks this worked, i had to define the i inside my functions each time to let it know where it shold switch, but other than that works perfect

Comment: I didn't get that clicking should interfere with the automatic switching, that's why I didn't set i in the functions. I just got that by reading your comment on amenadiel's answer ;) I have edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, altough there are more ellegant ways to do it

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".sle1").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-908px 0px'});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
             $(".sle2").click();
        },5000);
    });
    $(".sle2").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-681px 0px'});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
             $(".sle3").click();
        },5000);
    });
    $(".sle3").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").animate({backgroundPosition: '-454px 0px'});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
             $(".sle1").click();
        },5000);
    });

    window.setTimeout(function() {
             $(".sle1").click();
    },5000);
});
```

Comment: very simple and i could understand it as i'm a new to jquery, thank you

Comment: the only problem is, when its in step 2 and i click on step 1 it jums to step 3 and its not matched with the click function

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $(".sle1").trigger('click');

        setInterval(
            function() {
                $(".sle1").trigger('click');
            },
            15000
        );

    },
    5000
);

setTimeout(
    function() {
        $(".sle2").trigger('click');

        setInterval(
            function() {
                $(".sle2").trigger('click');
            },
            15000
        );

    },
    10000
);

setTimeout(
    function() {
        $(".sle3").trigger('click');

        setInterval(
            function() {
                $(".sle3").trigger('click');
            },
            15000
        );

    },
    15000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're willing  to improve your code, making it more concise, you could try the following, using [`window.setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
function changeBackground(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;
    function changer() {
        document.body.id = "b" + int;
        int++;
        if (int === frames) {
            int = 1;
        }
    }
    var swap = window.setInterval(changer, interval);
}
changeBackground(2000, 10); //milliseconds, frames
```

#### [Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/y2rqN/)

---

Talking about your example, it's harder to tell as it's not very clear.
Try adding `.stop()` and duration for your `.animate()` effects:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".sle1").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '-908px 0px'}, 5000);
    });
    $(".sle2").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '-681px 0px'}, 5000;
    });
    $(".sle3").click(function() {
        $(".slimgs").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '-454px 0px'}, 5000);
    });
});
```

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) - The jQuery `.stop()` method is used to stop animations or effects before it is finished.

Comment: instead of the `if (int === frames)`, you could use modulo division (See my answer). That's even more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, very nice idea, Johannes +1!